# if I find a bijection, rather than it is computable or not even computable, then the set would be denumerable or not?

Tags: computability

In "Computability: an introduction to recursive function theory", by Cutland, there is a theorem as follows:

**Theorem 2.4** $\mathcal{C}_n$ is denumerable.

where $\mathcal{C}_n$ represents the set of all $n$-ary computable functions. It constructs a bijection between $\mathcal{C}_n$ and $\mathbb{N}$ to show this as follows
$$
\left\{ \begin{matrix} f(0)=0 , \\ f(m+1) = \mu z \left(\Phi_z^{(n)} \neq \Phi_{f(0)}^{(n)} , \ldots , \Phi_{f(m)}^{(n)} \right) , \end{matrix}  \right. 
$$
where $\Phi_x^{(n)}$ represents a $n$-ary function encoded as $x$ by Godel number. But the problem is that it is not computable, in my opinion since it could be reduced to halting (Functions in $\mathcal{C}_n$ are partially recursive (computable))!

Now the question is that *if I find a bijection, rather than it is computable or not even computable, then the set would be denumerable or not?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For denumerability, all you need to do it to prove that a bijection *exists*. It need not be computable. There are $2^{\aleph_0}$ denumerable subsets of the natural numbers, and there are only countably many for which there is a computable bijection with the natural numbers.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. I would accept this answer as soon as I can (At least $8$ minutes should pass so I can accept an answer.).

Comment: There is no hurry! And do wait more than $8$ minutes, so that you have more answers to choose from.

Comment: OK! Thanks for your advice, I am a newcomer to math exchange. :)